# Create excel checkbox and lock other cells in the same row WITHOUT using macros

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to avoid macros to do the following:
when the user ticks a checkbox, it locks all other cells from the same row. If he unticks, it unlocks the cells...

At this moment my system does that using macros, but once clients makes me the favor of creating spreadsheets in my system with thousands of rows, the macros are making it work really really slow (sometimes it takes even hours to open the spreadsheet).

I'm just starting this study to see what I can do with excel checkboxes without using macros and I'd like to know if I can lock other cells depending on the checkbox is checked or not, without using macros. Is it possible? If so, then how? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but if the macro is taking hours to run over just a few thousand rows there is probably a number of opportunities to stream line the code and make it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

The answer has been given before, check out the following answer on StackOverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953214/excel-how-to-lock-cell-without-using-macros-if-possible/11954076#11954076

However, this is a little fiddly I think and I don't like fiddly spreadsheets as they tend to be unsupportable. As @gtwebb says, it might be worth sharing your code to see if it can be optimised.

---

You can prevent a user entering new data using only Data Validation

EDIT: use formula in list

Thanks to Head of Catering's comment, it is worth remembering that you can use formulas with Data Validation / List.

See his answer to another thread to see this in action: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11902463/138938

Original post

Walkthrough for Excel 2007:

```
Ribbon > Data > Data Validation
Authorize : Personnalized (or similar, my Excel is not in English sorry)
Enter this formula in the field:
    =IF(A1="",FALSE,TRUE)
```

Thus, you cannot enter a value in the cell if A1 is still empty

You can prevent a user entering new data using only Data Validation

EDIT: use formula in list

Thanks to Head of Catering's comment, it is worth remembering that you can use formulas with Data Validation / List.

See his answer to another thread to see this in action: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11902463/138938

Original post

Walkthrough for Excel 2007:

```
Ribbon > Data > Data Validation
Authorize : Personnalized (or similar, my Excel is not in English sorry)
Enter this formula in the field:
    =IF(A1="",FALSE,TRUE)
```

Thus, you cannot enter a value in the cell if A1 is still empty

Comment: the problem is not just how to lock cells... the solution I'm trying to find needs to lock the cell when the user ticks a checkbox. this is why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953214/excel-how-to-lock-cell-without-using-macros-if-possible/11954076#11954076 doesn't answer my question at all :/

Comment: you gave me an idea.. I'll do some tests.. if it works I'll share my code here